# What's the meaning of 'sb.'s heart fails'?

Tags: meaning

Merriam-Webster,
fail, verb,
1c. to stop functioning normally
*the patient's heart failed*

But there is an example in Longman that says:
*His heart failed and there was nothing we could do to save him.*
Which means his heart stopped working completely and he died.

So is this a sudden incident, or a continuous condition (= having heart failure)?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a sudden incident, and while it could be ongoing, that would normally be referred to with ‘undergoing heart failure’, as in

> Come quick! He’s undergoing heart failure.

Or any similar verb, like experiencing.

For very long term, ongoing failure of the heart — for example in old age — you might say ‘his heart is failing’, because it implies that it’s getting worse over a long period of time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Once again with a perfect answer. Thanks a lot man! Now I get it.